# How to compile all scss to style.css with Live Sass Compiler?

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, sass, live-sass-compiler

I have around 50 scss files in folder /scss. When im editing them i need compile it to one style.css with is in root. What exactly i have to add to settings?

```
"liveSassCompile.settings.formats": [
    {
     "format": "expanded",
     "extensionName": "style.css",
     "savePath": "/"
    }
   ],
```

This not works

I need this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
 "liveSassCompile.settings.formats":[
    // This is Default.
    {
        "format": "expanded",
        "extensionName": ".css",
        "savePath": null
    },
    // You can add more
    {
        "format": "compressed",
        "extensionName": ".min.css",
        "savePath": "/dist/css"
    },
    // More Complex
    {
        "format": "compressed",
        "extensionName": ".min.css",
        "savePath": "~/../css/"
    }
]
```

Comment: please explain your code

Comment: I found it generate css here: 
\scss\style.css but i need it in root not in scss folder. Also i dont understand why its not minificated.

Answer (score 0):

The extension is not a packing tool. You need a `style.scss` file that imports all of your files. Something like the below

```
@import './path/file1.scss';
@import './path/file2.scss';
@import './path/file3.scss';
```

Alternatively, see if webpack can be used